# ANR with Firebase InstanceId Receiver

Tags: android, firebase, crash, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have an app that makes use of FCM to receive push notifications, lately have been getting a lot of ANRs related to some execution that I'm not able to figure out. 
Broadcast of Intent { act=com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE flg=0x10000010 
pkg = {package name}|com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdReceiver(has extras)

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue is with the version of Firebase messaging that you are using. Try upgrading it to at least `17.3.2` which has a fix for the ANRs.

https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android#version_1732

Answer (score 0):

We experienced these ANRs a lot too and the only fix that reduced it was this suggestion of updating the dependencies to 21.1.0 that removes the dependency on FirebaseInstanceId which is always part of these crash logs: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-android-sdk/issues/2014#issuecomment-820390156

So, updating these dependencies from

```
implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-iid:20.1.1”
implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:20.1.2"
```

to

```
implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-iid:21.1.0”
implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:21.1.0"
```

results in:
[image]

Hasn't completely gotten rid of it but I hope it helps some of you.

Comment: I'm sure no one has this implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-iid:20.1.1” in his code and still fitting same ANR